How to filter dataframe if rows isin neither of multiple dataframes in an array?
This works:
df = df[~df.index.isin(df2['path']) & ~df.index.isin(df3['path'])]

How to re-write this so instead of hard-coding df2 and df3, it takes an array / list of dataframes?
Something like:
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df = df[~df.index.isin(dfX['path'] : dfs, &)]


Something like df[np.all([~df.index.isin(dfx['path']) for dfx in dfs], axis=0)]?

Or you could combine the path column of all dfs into a single series and then do a single ~isin check.

Following De Morgan's law, the union of all NOT ISIN is equivalent to NOT the intersection of all ISIN.
Thus you can get the union of all values as set and perform a single isin:
S = set().union(*(set(d['path']) for d in dfs))

out = df[~df.index.isin(S)]

As a one-liner:
out = df[~df.index.isin(set().union(*(set(d['path']) for d in dfs)))]

Example:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(4)}, index=list('abeg'))

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'path': list('abc')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'path': list('bcd')})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'path': list('cef')})

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

(df[~df.index.isin(df1['path']) & ~df.index.isin(df2['path']) & ~df.index.isin(df3['path'])]
 .equals(df[~df.index.isin(set().union(*(set(d['path']) for d in dfs)))])
)
# True


out = df[~df.index.isin(np.concatenate([d['path'].unique() for d in dfs]))]

or only pandas solution
out = df[~df.index.isin(pd.concat([d['path'] for d in dfs]))]

